# Handling highly correlated features

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering, feature-extraction, correlation, feature-construction

I have a data set of transactions and want to build a fraud detection model (classifier). Only 3 variables are given that could be used as input features. The number of transactions during past 3, 6 and 12 months. These three features are highly correlated. I want to use the information content in all three features as much as possible. What is the best way to handle their great amount of correlation.

Comment: My thinking is you really haven't defined the problem well. Provide more info. Are you looking to do Regression or Classification? Do you have only 3 features or more? Are you looking to reduce the number of features or use partial least squares to your advantage?

Comment: @oaxacamatt Thanks for your comment. I elaborated accordingly.

Comment: @user2348674 if there are only 3 variables and they are all highly correlated then I'm afraid you can't build any model. Correlation detection and treatment is a dimensionality reduction method. Say you set a cut-off point of 0.75 and find two out of three variables meet the criteria. Then are you going to build a model using just one variable?